# $f\sim g \iff f \bar{g} \sim c_p$ for paths $f,g$

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a path connected topological space, $p,q \in X$ points. Let $f,g: [0,1] \to X$ be two paths from $p$ to $q$. Then $$f\sim g \iff f \bar{g} \sim c_p$$

Ok, $f\sim g$ means that there is a continuous $H: X \times [0,1] \to X$ such that $H(x,0) = f(x)$ and $H(x,1)=g(x)$, and that $H$ leaves the end points $p$, $q$ fixed for all times.

From this, how do we get a $K: X \times [0,1] \to X$ where $K_0 = f \bar{g}$ and $K_1 = c_p$, which also leaves the end points fixed at all times?

Comment: http://at.yorku.ca/p/a/c/a/09.pdf might inspire you (see last of page 4, beginning of page 5; it needs a little adaptation, maybe)

Comment: The inverse path is sometimes denoted by $g^{-}$, is that what you intended?

Comment: Yes Pedro, that is what I meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume that by $\bar{g}$ you mean the inverse path $\bar{g}(t) = g(1-t)$.
I'll show $f \sim g \implies f\bar{g} \sim c_{p}$.  By looking at the link Henno posted one can see that what we want to do is travel along $f$, move from $f$ to $g$ along our given homotopy $H$, and then move backwards along $g$ (i.e. forwards along $\bar{g}$) to $p$.  Explicitly, we define our new homotopy as
$$K(x,t) = \begin{cases} 
f(2x) & x \in [0, \frac{1-t}{2}]\\
H(1-t, \frac{1}{t}(x - \frac{1-t}{2})) & x \in [\frac{1-t}{2}, \frac{1+t}{2}]\\
g(2-2x) & x \in [\frac{1+t}{2}, 1]
\end{cases}
$$
I'll leave you to check that this matches up at the endpoints, is continuous, and can be well-defined at $t=0$.

Comment: I see now, thank u very much